# How to update heroku app (Node js) from github repo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have tried the same as React deploy precess.

```
git status
git remote add origin <repo link>
git commit -m "node js"
git add .
```

**But it does not work.**

can you know me how to update the node js app in Github that I have been uploaded to the Heroku server.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git add` to stage before you `git commit`?

Comment: sorry, i was some line mistake. now i have edited.

Comment: but this process does not work.

Comment: Actually, I don't now the right process how to update the Heroku app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app deployment settings, add a repository to link your app with it :

[image]

After that you can enable the automatic deploy on a specific branch and each push or deploy manually a branch.

[image]

Comment: I have already uploaded my project, but now i need to update some code in my project.

Comment: update your code, push your commit in your github repo normally and deploy the branch in your heroku dashboard